# Add file to jar during maven build

Tags: java, build, jar, maven

I have an xslt that I want to add to my jar file when I do the maven build. I read int he documentation you can add stuff in the resources folder, and it will get picked up, but what if I want it to show up in a different folder - how do I make it go there in the jar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If it's a JAR just add it in `src/main/resources` replicating the folder structure you want to be present in the JAR (the classpath root for a JAR is the very first level on it so it's easy).

In case of a WAR or other package types the method is very different

Comment: I'll add that adding to a nested folder inside your JAR is usually not needed, unless your App is specifically looking for that resource in that structure (as opposed to the general CLASSPATH available to it)

Comment: Hi I'm very new to this, just wondering can you explain more about 'If it's a JAR just add it in src/main/resources replicating the folder structure you want to be present in the JAR (the classpath root for a JAR is the very first level on it so it's easy).' How to achieve this step by step? Many thanks.